# Problems with R script for Hill Equation

Tags: r, statistics

I found the following R script [here](https://www.r-project.org/conferences/useR-2009/slides/Thorin+Mallem+Noireaud+Desfontis.pdf) which is used to fit your data with the Hill equation to get an EC50 and the like.
I'm new to R and thus ran into a problem.
The error message is

> Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
>     only defined on a data frame with all numeric variables

So far I found out that it could be a problem with my data, but even if I enter some data directly into the script I get this error message.
If anyone could point me in the right direction I would be very happy. Thanks!

Here is my "modified" script with some data I entered:

```
library(nlme)
library(intervals)

conc <- c(500, 250, 125, 62, 31, 15)  
Fnorm <- c(818, 869, 865, 868, 885, 895)  
DataSet <- data.frame(conc, Fnorm)  
Hill1<-function(x, Em, n, D){Em/(1 + 10^(n * (D - x)))}  
EstH.Pop<-function(DataSet)
    {InitVal<-function(DataSet){
          xy<-sortedXyData(DataSet$LogC,DataSet$Response,DataSet)
          Em<-max(xy[c(2)])
          D<-NLSstClosestX(xy,Em/2)
          n<-1
          value<-c(Em,n,D)
          value}  
DataSet.nlme<-nlme(Response~Hill1(LogC,Em,n,D),DataSet,fixed=Em+n+D~1,random=Em+D+n~1,groups=~Identity,weights=varPower(),cor=corAR1(),start=c(Em=InitVal(DataSet)[c(1)],n=InitVal(DataSet)[c(2)],D=InitVal(DataSet)[c(3)]))}  
summary(EstH.Pop(DataSet))  
CI.par<-function(DataSet){intervals(EstH.Pop(DataSet))}  
CI.par(DataSet)
```

Comment: Why are you trying to fit a mixed effects model to data without a grouping variable?

Comment: Also, the names of your dataset columns don't correspond to the model formula.

Comment: would you care to elaborate "your dataset columns don't corresppond to the model formula"?

Answer (score 0):

Your DataSet has two columns named "conc" and "Fnorm". Your are using the formula `Response~Hill1(LogC,Em,n,D)`. Up to the documentation: **If data is given, all names used in the formula should be defined as
parameters or variables in the data frame**. So in your DataSet there is no column named "Response" and moreover you are using the Hill1 function in the formula.

Regards

Comment: thanks! I renamed the columns accordingly and the error vanished. But now I get a new one saying "object 'Identity' not found". The only "Identity" the script uses is within the nlme function "groups=~Identity". Looking at the nlme documentation tells me that "groups" is the part of my data in which the random effect should take place. But I'm not sure what "~Identity", in this case, means.

Comment: Is 'Identity' a column in your dataset? try writing "groups = ~ Identity"(check spaces!!) and check if the Identity column is of class factor.